# I want to transform something in notepad++ using regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

Ok so look for example I got this 3 rows:

```
2536320:GlorySon:Maximono@web.de:84.153.217.22:a6b585f1ba0461ae2ae30cca72c5d9e0:J3!'Zau&@s`IlB%\\gDhqk>K8~W,QSP
470957:Redemptor:got_lowrider@hotmail.com:24.77.161.226:daa4f847e4c2eef69d3fd30bab8c8ae2:]2a
49114:Lavis:Albert_Rene@voila.fr:82.236.195.211:8db988462a0c5403a4c2afc2c4e5f87d:/<I
```

I want to transform them to:

```
Maximono@web.de
got_lowrider@hotmail.com
Albert_Rene@voila.fr
```

Can anyone help me with a regular expression in order to get the result i want :))

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to pull out just the e-mail address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will pull out all e-mail addresses, which appears to be your requirement

`\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b`

You can test it here https://regex101.com/r/jrncm1/1

Comment: @davyd: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?:([^:@]+@[^:]+).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .+?           # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  :             # a colon
  (             # start group 1
    [^:@]+      # 1 or more any character that is not : or @
    @           # @ sign
    [^:]+       # 1 or more any character that is not :
  )             # end group
  .*            # 0 or more any charactre but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Maximono@web.de
got_lowrider@hotmail.com
Albert_Rene@voila.fr
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]